# Mocking Ionic Native Support in Browser

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

Trying to mock Ionic Native Network in browser. To do so, I added the `class` in my **`app.module.ts`** as follows:

```
    ...
    import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
    ...
    ...    
    export class NetworkMock extends Network{      
      type = 'none';
    }
@NgModule({ ....


providers: [ 
...
...

{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
{provide: Network, useClass: NetworkMock}
```

With the above, when I call the following function in a component:

```
check_network() {    
    console.log(this.net.type);    
}
```

I get `null` in the browser console

**How can I get it working correctly ? Am i not supposed to get `'none'` ?**

The following is the output from ionic-info :

```
global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
    Cordova CLI      : 6.5.0
    Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.0
    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
    Cordova Platforms               : none
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.0.1

System:

    Node       : v6.9.1
    OS         : Windows 7
    Xcode      : not installed
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
    npm        : 3.10.8
```

What is going wrong ? Please help.

Comment: please take a look at my answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44632637/ionic-change-import-library-based-on-isdebugmode/44639129#44639129). If you think it may work on your end, I can add it as an answer in this thread as well.

Comment: did you follow https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/ ?

Comment: @sebaferreras I just rephrased the code and did not EXTEND the 'NetworkMock' to inherit the actual 'Network' class - the code worked !! it correctly returned 'none' on my browser console. Is this due to the weird nature of Javascript Inheritance ???

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to do things a little bit different when it comes to using a cordova plugin in the browser. Even though your approach works great, you still need to manually tell Angular which class should be used when it sees a `Network` parameter in some component's constructor. You do that in this line:

```
{ provide: Network, useClass: NetworkMock }
```

**So if you want to run the app on a mobile device, you'd need to manually change that line** (and all the lines related to some other cordova plugins as well).

That's why I like to use a **[factory provider](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#factory-providers)** instead. This is how I work with the `Network` cordova plugin in the browser:

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------
// File: /providers/cordova-plugins/network/network.provider.ts
// ------------------------------------------------------------

// Ionic
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

// Ionic native
// http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/network/
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';

// Browser implementation
export class BrowserNetworkProvider extends Network {

    public get type(): string {
        return this.isOnline() ? 'wify' : 'none';
    }

    private isOnline(): boolean {
        return navigator.onLine;
    }
}

// Mobile implementation
// Is empty in this case since I don't to override anything, but in 
// some other plugins, I like to add some console.log() before calling
// the methods in the plugin (by using super.nameOfTheMethod();)
export class MobileNetworkProvider extends Network {}

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// Network factory
//    parameters: dependencies of the target service
//    returns: instance of the service (for real devices or the browser)
// ------------------------------------------------------------
export function networkFactory(platform: Platform) {
    return platform.is('cordova') ? new MobileNetworkProvider() : new BrowserNetworkProvider();
}

// networkProvider: used to import the service in the NgModule declaration
export let networkProvider =
    {
        provide: Network,
        useFactory: networkFactory,
        deps: [Platform]
    };
```

And then in the `app.module.ts` file:

```
import { networkProvider } from '../providers/plugins/network/network.provider';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyApp,
        //...
    ],
    imports: [
        // ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
        // ...
    ],
    providers: [
        // Cordova plugins
        networkProvider, // <- I'm using our custom provider here! :)

        // ...
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**As you can see, Angular will use the `Platform` information to know which extension of the `Network` class should be used in our app.**

---

As we talked about in the comments:

1) Regarding the getter to override the `type` property, I don't know that much of Typescript, but for some reason I was not able to set the value of a property when extending a class (that's why I suggested using the getter instead). Since a getter is called just like if it were a property, I though about doing it like that and seems to be working!

2) Why extending the `Network` class for the browser, when we could also use a class that has nothing to do with the `Network` class (like when you omit the `extend` keyword in your example? Well, you could do that, since after all this is just Javascript (and you can fix any Typescript complain using the `(<any>propertyName)` cast. But since you're telling Angular which implementation of the `Network` class should be used, why not extending that class, overriding what we want to change, but keeping everything consistent? **If later the plugin add some methods that works on the browser, you won't need to change anything, since you're already using the *real* implementation of the plugin for all the methods that you don't override.**

Comment: I agree. This is the best solution I have found on the internet. And I have searched a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear that @MarioShtika :)

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the following alternative and it **worked**.

```
...
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
...
...    
export class NetworkMock{   
 // I omitted the Extend keyword and avoided overriding the actual class   
 type = 'none';
}
@NgModule({ ....


providers: [ 
...
...

{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
{provide: Network, useClass: NetworkMock}
```

With the code above, now the browser console correctly prints **'none'** or whatever value I put in the type property of the `NetworkMock` class.

To my understanding, the Inheritance is Javascript is tricky in nature and comes up with undesirable circumstances. So I avoided it completely. However, in the `providers` array I referenced my `NetworkMock` in `useClass` property.

**Any further insight will be highly appreciated**.

Comment: I think that worked because it's doing something different. When extending the `Network` class with your mock, you're _adding new features_. When omitting the `extend`, you're just creating a new class that has nothing to do with the `Network` class from Ionic Native. That being said, could you please try by adding the extend, but using a getter instead of a property? I'd be like this: `export class NetworkMock extends Network { public get type() { return 'none'; } }`. I'm pretty sure it will work now, but just test it if you can to be sure...

Comment: @sebaferreras  thank you very much for the input. I will test ASAP and will definitely let you know about the update.Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hi @sebaferreras  I just tested with your suggestion and it worked. Thanks for your help. But for academic reasons - let me ask you - if I create a getter function instead of a property - I am actually modifying the NetworkMock class even if it is a child class of Network and I am not overriding the original 'type' property defined on the super class. As a result, when the method is called it looks for the getter function and not the property. The question is .. what is the difference between my approach as above and the way you suggested ?

Comment: I've added an answer with some details, and the reasons why I prefer the other approach... but again, sometimes it's just a _matter of taste_ and there're a lot of possible ways to do this, and all of them are valid options :)