# Ionic3 document viewer plugin not work

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3, ionic-native

**Ionic Info**

```
tushar@localhost:~/.../Ionic3/CornerStone/cornerstone-parent$ ionic info

cli packages: (/home/tushar/workspace/Ionic3/CornerStone/cornerstone-parent/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 7.0.1

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.0.2
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 browser 4.1.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.5.3

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.0.2
    Node              : v6.11.2
    npm               : 3.10.10
    OS                : Linux 4.11
```

I used [Document Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/admxu.png) plugin in my app.
it gives error: **Error in SitewaertsDocumentViewer.viewDocument(): Missing Command Error**

Test with this command: **ionic serve** and **ionic cordova run browser**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Test with this command: ionic serve and ionic cordova run browser

I'm afraid that since it's a cordova plugin, it won't work on the browser. You need to execute your app in a simulator / physical device in order to use cordova plugins:

`ionic cordova run android` / `ionic cordova run ios`

Comment: Or he can `Mock` that if he wants no?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44801898/mocking-ionic-native-support-in-browser/44819361#44819361) you can find a way to mock the plugins in the browser, but still, if you want to add the _document viewer_ feature to your app, you'll need to use another javascript-related way to add it when running the app on the browser...

Comment: it's better to use IOS/Android simulator and debug using google/safarie  remote device